# How to subscribe to all ethereum log events for any erc721 or ERC1155 contracts

Tags: ethereum

I'm already able to filter my subscription by contract address, I'm wondering if someone has suggestion for filtering only ERC721 or 1155.

Otherwise I have to get and decode everything which I am hoping to avoid.

Comment: What do you mean by "I'm already able to filter my subscription by contract address..." and "...filtering only ERC721 or 1155."?! You want to filter by all ERC721 or 1155 tokens or all transactions of one ERC721 or 1155 token?!

Comment: I can get logs for a list of contracts but I want them for all ERC721 / 1155 contracts.

Comment: In that case, I did not find anything, sorry